# Are different hair styles topologically similiar

Tags: general-topology

I am new to math and topology. Suppose there are $4$ ladies. One wears her hair straight down her back. Another splits them into $2$ parts and wears them across each shoulder. The third lady wears a single plait. The fourth knots a bun on top of her head. Are these $4$ hair styles topologically similar?

Comment: The bun and the straight down hairstyle of the $4$th and $1$st lady are topologically similar. The first lady's hair and second lady's hair are not topologically similar (because the partition of the second lady's hair into 2 parts)

Comment: Okay thanks. I only knew about donut and tea cup.